# Is it safe to use an untrusted bookmarklet on a web page with sensitive data?

Tags: javascript, security, bookmarklet

Is it safe to use an untrusted [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) on a web page containing sensitive data, for example internet banking page? In particular, can a bookmarklet send the data anywhere or execute some actions (like following links) on the page?

Comment: This isn't really a programming problem, voting to migrate to SuperUser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it safe to use an untrusted bookmarklet on a web page containing sensitive data, for example internet banking page?

No.

> In particular, can a bookmarklet send the data anywhere or execute some actions (like following links) on the page?

Yes.

A bookmarklet runs some JavaScript *as if it were included on the page by the page author* (with all the permissions that implies).

Comment: "as if it were included on the page by the page author." I think it can do even more, at least on some browsers it is closer to what a browser extension can do.

Comment: @Thilo Bookmarklets get no special privileges in any of the newer version of IE, Firefox, or Chrome. I'm not as confident about Safari and Opera, but I seriously doubt it. But they are plenty dangerous enough without any special permission if you don't know what they do. Should generally avoid using them on on highly critical websites.

Comment: I'm surprised that browsers don't warn you against dragging a bookmarklet into your bookmarks. A simple "This link is not just a website link, it's code that can do anything on any website that you visit, when you click it. Are you sure you want to add it?" would be enough. Wow.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not safe.

A bookmarklet can see everything on the page, read its cookies and its local storage, and interact with the server the page came from (and I even think other servers as well, as the cross-domain-sandboxing may not apply to bookmarklets).

Comment: The same sandboxing applies to a bookmarklet as would apply to normal Javascript run on the page.